# Validation on page with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put validation on a page that have two divs

```
<form>
    <div id="first>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="second" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" name="phone">
        <button id="finish">Finish</button>
        <button id="back">Back</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

so when I click `#next` it shows the second div, but I want to check validation for that div only.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, ids' have to be unique

Comment: Maybe you can use `class` instead of an `id`

Comment: Sorry guys, I fixed the question

Answer (score 2):

Since you've included jQuery in the tags, you should definitely stick with jQuery plugins. This save you a lot of unnecessary work.

Some of the form wizard plugins:

- [jformslider](http://jformslider.com/)
- [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples)
- [jquery wizard](https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-wizard)
- [stepify](https://github.com/ryansukale/stepify)

If you really need for custom form wizard, you could start with something like this (according to your HTML sample) :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5o60wkz/)

```
<form method="post">
  <div id="first">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="second" style="display:none;">
    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone">
    <button id="finish">Finish</button>
    <button id="back">Back</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#next').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if($('#name').val() == ''){
       return alert('Type name!');            
      }
      $('#second').show();
      $('#first').hide();
    });

    $('#finish').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('hello ' + $('#name').val() + '! \nYour phone nr. is: ' + $('#phone').val());
    });

    $('#back').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#first').show();
      $('#second').hide();
    }); 

  });
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5o60wkz/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `#next` for all three of your buttons. If you would like to check validation for one div only, you should make all of your IDs different

```
<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="finish">Finish</button>
<button id="back">Back</button>
```

Let's say you only want to check validation for the `#next` div.

You can then use the JQuery selector `$(#next)`

It is still possible, even if all of your buttons have the same ID

You can use `$(#next:first)` to select the first button with id `#next`

However please keep in mind one thing

`Classes` can be used multiple times on a page

`IDs` should generally only be used once per page